# how to change value with Ember.js Array forEach?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
 self.resultList.forEach(function(item, index, enumerable){
                         console.log(self.resultList);
                         item.id=11;
                         item.get('id');
                     });
```

the item like this:
[image]

if `item.id = 11;`
the exception like this:

> Assertion failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of
>   [object Object])

so item.get('id') or item.set('id',11)

the exception like this

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'get'

is this item not the Ember's Object?so what the item is?

could someone tell me  how to change the 'itme.id's value..

Thanks a million

Comment: What is inside self.resultList? I think the array contains both plain JS Objects and Ember Objects.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `Ember.set(yourObject, propertyName, value);` and `Ember.get(yourObject, propertyName);` to safely set and get properties.

In your case:

```
self.resultList.forEach(function(item, index, enumerable) {
    Ember.set(item, "id", 11); 
    Ember.get(item, "id");
});
```

Comment: the exception like this:You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object Object])

Comment: Strange, this error happens when you use obj.prop = value; instead of obj.set("prop", value); And in my aswer is used it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did it in this way

```js
//In my controller I've defined the array
displayInfoCheckboxes: [
    {
      turnover: {
        label: "Turnover",
        value: 1,
        propertyName: "turnover"
      }
    }, {
      pl: {
        label: "P&L",
        value: 1
      }
    }
]

//and in my handler I passed the full string path to the property in the set method

let displayInfoCheckboxes = this.get('displayInfoCheckboxes');
let controller = this;

displayInfoCheckboxes.forEach(function(items,index) {
  for (var key in items) {
    controller.set('displayInfoCheckboxes.' + index + '.' + key + '.value', false);
  }
})
```