# Ember.js binding on array inside a property

Tags: arrays, binding, ember.js

Hello emberjs experts :)

There is something that i don't understand.

Given the following route:

```
Evibe.MemberShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('/api/user').then(function(user) {
            return Ember.Object.create(user);
        });
    }
});
```

The call to the api simply returns a user object containing properties. One of this property is an array of picture objects. Like that:

```
{
    username: "A nice user",
    pictures: [
        {id: 1, is_main: true,  url: 'http://www.test.com/img1.jpg'},
        {id: 2, is_main: false, url: 'http://www.test.com/img2.jpg'},
        {id: 3, is_main: false, url: 'http://www.test.com/img3.jpg'},
        {id: 4, is_main: false, url: 'http://www.test.com/img4.jpg'},
    ]
}
```

In my controller, i have something like this:

```
Evibe.MemberShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    nb_pictures: function() {
        return this.pictures.length;
    }.property('pictures'),

    addPictureObject: function(picture) {
        this.get('pictures').addObject(picture);
    }
});
```

And in my template, i have something like this:

```
{{ nb_pictures }} pictures
```

I don't understand why nb_pictures is not updated, as i'm adding an object into my "pictures" property with the addPictureObject function.

Also, when i try to do something like this:

```
this.get('pictures').setEach('is_main', false);                   // Works
this.get('pictures').findBy('id', pictureId).is_main = true;      // Doesn't work
this.get('pictures').findBy('id', pictureId).set('is_main', true) // Doesn't work
```

The first line works as expected.

But... for the second line, i get the error: "Assertion failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object Object])"

And for the third one, i get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'set' "

Any ideas that can help clarify this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `nb_pictures` computed property, you have set the dependent key with `property('pictures')`, the correct is `property('pictures.length')`.

This is the updated code:

```
Evibe.MemberShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    nb_pictures: function() {
        return this.get('pictures.length');
    }.property('pictures.length'),

    addPictureObject: function(picture) {
        this.get('pictures').addObject(picture);
    }
});
```

Using just `property('pictures')` will make the framework observe just the array replacement, like `set('pictures', [...])`, not the changes in the array structure `get('pictures').pushObject(...)`. this the reason that your ui don't update.

Comment: Excellent ! The nb_pictures works as expected now :) Thanks You ! Any idea about my second problem about modify a property of an object in my array ?

Comment: Just found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976333/how-to-change-value-with-ember-js-array-foreach Again, many thanks Marcio