# Ember.js - How do I set the property of an element within an ArrayProxy?

Tags: ember.js

If I'm using an ArrayProxy in my model, I cannot find a way to update the properties of a specific element within that array.

Here's my sample route and controller:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
        content : [
            { firstName : "Bob", lastName : "Smith" }, 
            { firstName : "George", lastName : "Jhnsn"}
        ]
    });
  }
});


App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions : {
        fixGeorgesLastName : function(){
            // how to I change the last name to 'Johnson' ???
            console.log(this.get("model").objectAt(1).lastName); // Jhnsn
            var georgeObjFromModel = this.get("model").objectAt(1);
            console.log(georgeObjFromModel.lastName); // Jhnsn

            // georgeObjFromModel.objectAt(1).lastName = "Johnson";  // error !!!  TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'objectAt'

        }
    }
});
```

How do I change the `lastName` value of the second element?

I can figure out how to do it for a local version of the same array:

```
// local instance of same array
var localCustomerArray = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content : [
        { firstName : "Bob", lastName : "Smith" }, 
        { firstName : "George", lastName : "Jhnsn"}
    ]
});

// works fine
console.log("before: " + localCustomerArray.objectAt(1).lastName);  // Jhnsn
localCustomerArray.objectAt(1).lastName = "Johnson";
console.log("after: " + localCustomerArray.objectAt(1).lastName);  // Johnson
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found answer via [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976333/how-to-change-value-with-ember-js-array-foreach)

It can be updated using the `Ember.set` method:

```
var georgeObjFromModel = this.get("model").objectAt(1);
Ember.set(georgeObjFromModel, "lastName", "Johnson");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
this.get("model").set(1+'.lastName', 'Johnson');
```

Why can't we just do the following?

```
this.get("model").get(1).set('lastName', 'Johnson');
```

Comment: You can't do the second in all scenarios because the object at that index must be an Ember Object in order to leverage get/set semantics. You'll note that the accepted answer leverages the global get/set ins Ember in order to get around the same issue.

Comment: @nathanhammond So is the preferred to somehow wrap all properties so that they're ember objects or use these methods for setting?

Comment: The preference is based upon the needs of the application. In simplistic scenarios like these it doesn't make sense to move away from POJOs, but more complicated applications will almost by default convert things into Ember objects in order to leverage computed properties.